How to separate a column formula in different parts
How to separate a column formula in different parts?
=IF(Urgency*Importance=1,"Low")

Above works well.
But if I add:
=IF(Urgency*Importance=1,"Low"), =IF(Urgency*Importance=2,"Medium")

it doesn't works. How should I do it?

Have you tried the solution provided in the answer? Any prograss?

You will have to use nested IF functions in your SharePoint calculated column formula.
Example:
=IF(Urgency*Importance=1,"Low",IF(Urgency*Importance=2,"Medium",IF(Urgency*Importance=3,"High","")))

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

